# Is my Windows Install corrupted, or do I just have two isolated issues?

Tags: windows, boot

So on the night of November 30th, I ran into a problem with my PC. I have multiple user accounts on the PC, and was signing into a different account than my daily driver. Only problem was that I had a registry error, on that prevented me from logging on. Specifically the "User Account Service." I do not remember 100%. So I was able to fix that with a system restore point, and all was good. Until it happened again, that same day. Pretty dumb of me to recreate the issue, but it is what it is.

I fixed that with a system reset, as I only had the two restore points. *I have since set-up a recurring system restore point at every startup* All was fine until this morning, Dec. 2 when my system would not boot at all. It was missing a System32 file, and giving me the error code 0xc00000f. Specifically it was missing the `winload.efi` file.

To fix it I tried using the command prompt in the windows recovery, but that did not work. Running sfc commands just kept failing. I ran `DISM.exe`, which just plain did not run. Using bcdedit commands did not work. I had to do another system restore point in order to fix it. I had a few to work with.

Now however, I have a weird issue where Microsoft Office apps will not work on my PC. They were already installed, but then just disappeared off my system, and the Microsoft store cannot download them again. My question is the following:

1. What else could I have tried to fix either my boot issue or my sign-in issue that I did not do?
2. How do I verify that my critical system files are in fact working properly, and I will not have this problem in the future?
3. What are all of the ways I should be backing up my data so I can just reset if need be? I am doing some things already, but maybe not everything I should be.
4. Any ideas on the Office apps issue?

---

Results of a quick wmic status check and the chkdsk c: command:

[image: Results of a quick wmic status check and the chkdsk c: command]

Also a few new developments:

1. Ignore the Office question, I was able to get it figured out. It was just partially installed files.
2. My `c:\windows\programfiles\windowsapps` folder is corrupted. the permission entry for WindowsApps shows that This Access control entry is corrupt. Delete it and create a new one. I changed the ownership to my account, and then back. I am still having an issue while trying to run a few apps as an Admin. It is apps which are located in this folder.

Comment: Ah, so you have Schrodinger's backup - nobody knows if it works until you need it :) Still better than average person, so that's something. Definitely check drive's SMART attributes, you can post them here ([edit]).

Comment: Sounds like a storage problem.  Your Microsoft Office problem is separate from your continuous failures, even if I wanted to address your office problem, I wouldn’t be able to do so with the little information you have provided

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It's not searchable, not accessible to people dependent on screen readers and looks bad on high-resolution screens.